# Why does my link break when i use data-toggle attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I used data toggle attribute with my link and i can't figure out why it breaks my link, that is, nothing happens when i click the link. Here is the line of code:

```
<%= link_to 'Users', dashboard_users_path, data: { toggle: 'tab' } %>
```

I can visit the url directly so nothing wrong with the link without the data-attribute.

Comment: Damn, that dup target has a terrible title. Let me steal this one :)

Comment: How does the `HTML` for that `link_to` looks like?

Comment: @Pavan it looks like this <a data-toggle="tab" href="/dashboard/users">Users</a>